# Prove that $(x^q)' = qx^{q-1}, \quad \forall q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that $(x^q)' = qx^{q-1}, \quad \forall q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x \geq 0$.

Proving that $(x^n)' = nx^{n-1}, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ was an easy proof by induction.

But induction does not apply to this one. Hint is given that we can use the identity: $$u^m - v^m = (u - v)(u^{m-1} + u^{m-2}v + \ldots + uv^{m-2} + v^{m-1})$$ with $u = x^{n/m}$ and $v = a^{n/m}$.

This does not help me at the moment. What am I missing here?

Comment: First: $x^q$ is not defined for all real $x$. With $q=1/2$,  is $(-1)^q?$ Usually, we restrict $x^q$ to $x\geq 0$ or $x>0$.

Comment: Sure. I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{\tfrac nm}-a^{\tfrac nm}}{x-a}&=\frac{\Bigl(x^{\tfrac nm}-a^{\tfrac nm}\Bigr)\Bigl(x^{\tfrac{n(m-1)}m}+x^{\tfrac{n(m-2)}m}a^{\tfrac nm}++x^{\tfrac{n(m-3)}m}a^{\tfrac {2n}m}\dots+a^{\tfrac{n(m-1)}m}\Bigr)}{(x-a)\Bigl(x^{\tfrac{n(m-1)}m}+x^{\tfrac{n(m-2)}m}a^{\tfrac nm}+x^{\tfrac{n(m-3)}m}a^{\tfrac {2n}m}\dots+a^{\tfrac{n(m-1)}m}\Bigr)}\\
&=\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}\cdot\frac1{x^{\tfrac{n(m-1)}m}+x^{\tfrac{n(m-2)}m}a^{\tfrac nm}+x^{\tfrac{n(m-3)}m}a^{\tfrac {2n}m}\dots+a^{\tfrac{n(m-1)}m}}
\end{align*}
As $x$ tends to $a$, the first fraction tends to the derivative of $x^n$ at $a$, $\;na^{n-1}$, and the denominator of the second fraction tends to $\;ma^{\tfrac{n(m-1)}m}$, hence the product tends to:
$$\frac nm a^{n-1-\tfrac{n(m-1)}m}=\frac nm a^{\tfrac nm-1}.$$

Comment: Proving that the denominator in the second fraction tends to $ma^{\frac{n(m-1)}{m}}$ as $x \to a$ rigorously is a bit daunting using epsilon-delta.

Comment: You didn't mention you have to do it with ε-δ. Without ε-δ, it simply results from the continuity of polynomial functions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing $q=\frac{m}{n}$ for $m,n$ integers.

Define $y = x^{\frac{m}{n}}$. Then $y^n = x^m$

$\frac{d}{dx}(y^n) = ny^{n-1}\frac{dy}{dx}$ (since you know power rule it's true for integers), and similarly, $\frac{d}{dx}(x^m) = mx^{m-1}$.

Equating these two since they're the same:

$mx^{m-1} = ny^{n-1}\frac{dy}{dx}$

So: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{mx^{m-1}}{ny^{n-1}}$

Substituting $y = x^{\frac{m}{n}}$ back in and simplifying should give the final result

Comment: The chain rule only works if you know both are differentiable, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This proof uses an approach similar to Brenton's but it shows the statement for any real number.

Let  $y = x^m$ then

$$\ln(y) = \ln(x^m)$$
$$\ln(y) = m\ln(x)$$

Now differentiate
$$\frac{y'}{y} = \frac{m}{x}$$
$$y' = \frac{m{y}}{x}$$
$$y' = \frac{mx^m}{x}$$
$$y' = mx^{m-1}$$

Comment: This actually uses the hypothesis that $x\mapsto x^m$ is differentiable; but it can be fixed by writing the function as $\exp(m\ln x)$ and applying the chain rule.

Comment: The question asked for a derivation of the formula not a proof of differentiability.